# Django process running tasks instead of Celery

Tags: django, celery

I'm running an app with Celery+redis for asynchronous tasks.
I managed to get Celery see the list of tasks. However my tasks aren't executed by Celery workers but by Django process instead.

I tried invoking the tasks with `.delay()` and `.apply_async()` without success (actually in these cases the call to the task gets blocked indefinitely and nothing is shown in the logs).
I might be missing something very basic but cannot see where.

Relevant settings follow:

#### settings.py

```py
CELERY_REDIS_DB = os.environ.get("REDIS_DB_CELERY", 0)
CELERY_REDIS_HOST = os.getenv("REDIS_HOSTNAME", "redis")
CELERY_REDIS_PORT = 6379
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = BROKER_URL = (
    f'redis://{CELERY_REDIS_HOST}:{CELERY_REDIS_PORT}/{CELERY_REDIS_DB}'
)
CELERY_TIMEZONE = TIME_ZONE
CELERY_RESULT_EXPIRES = 5 * 60 * 60
```

#### celery.py

```py
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'maat.settings')
app = Celery('maat')

# Using a string here means the worker don't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

#### tasks.py

```py
@shared_task
def remove_task(
    environment=None,
    payload=None,
    **kwargs,
):
    LOGGER.info('Received task, now removing')
    ...
```

#### views.py

```py
class MyClass(
    LoginRequiredMixin,
    PermissionRequiredMixin,
    SingleObjectMixin,
    APIView
):
    return_403 = True
    model = models.Environment
    slug_field = 'name'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'environment'

    def delete(self, request, environment):
        tasks.remove_task(environment=environment, payload=request.data)
```

- Django 3.2
- celery[redis] 5.1.2
- redis 3.5.3
- django-celery-results 2.0.1

Comment: Are you sure you haven't accidentally set the "always eager" option somewhere?

Comment: Hi, I just double-checked and nope, that isn't set.

Comment: Do both celery and django reside in the same directory?

Comment: Well basically yes, just followed the guidelines from https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `celery.py` lives somewhere that is accessible to `views.py`, the problem is likely that because you are using a shared task, django does not know how to communicate with the celery broker without more information.

In order to do that, we can [follow the advice from our helpful friends at stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52372117/how-to-call-a-celery-shared-task) and do something like the following in your view:

```
from path.to.celery import app
app.set_default()
```

Comment: although that was not exactly the solution, your explanation is indeed correct and pointed me to the fact that I did not import the celery app in project's __init__.py